# How to avoid WMI DirectoryEntry caching failed connections

Tags: wmi, directoryservices, directoryentry

When making a WMI call using DirectoryEntry in C# it appears that a failure is cached so that retries immediately fail without retrying.

Here's what I've done to reproduce this:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
directoryEntry.Username = connectUsername;
directoryEntry.Password = connectPassword;
directoryEntry.Path = "WinNT://" + connectServerName + ",computer";
newUser = directoryEntry.Children.Add(userName, "user");
```

- Make a call to a VM that has the firewall blocking the connection.
- It will take a while and then it will fail with "The network path was not found"
- However, if I enable the firewall rule and try again, WMI will immediately throw the same network path error.
- It's only after a wait (I'm unsure now long, but a few minutes) can I retry and it will notice that the network is working.

The code is in a WCF service where every call should be fresh to new instances of everything.

Any ideas on where the caching is occurring and how can I ensure that a new DirectoryEntry makes a fresh call?

Update: 
I just tried an iisreset (both the site and web service) and the caching is still occurring. I then restarted the *Windows Management Instrumentation* service and then it made a fresh un-cached call. So this lets me realize that the issue isn't with the C#/WCF code, or the network, but it's with WMI. Any ideas how to force WMI to make a fresh un-cached call?

Comment: Have you tried setting the DirectoryEntry's `UsePropertyCache` property to false, or calling `RefreshCache()`?

Comment: @stuartd, yes, I should have mentioned. I did try both but they didn't appear to help with this situation.